# Accessing parent view controller (custom) properties

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I have written a `UITabBarController` subclass (called `MainViewController`) and added a few instance variables, specifically a venue of type Venue. Each tab of the `MainViewController` needs to access the venue variable of the `MainViewController`. In the first tab, a `UIViewController` subclass named `HomeViewController`, I wrote my `viewDidLoad` method and tried to output to NSLog with both...

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.parentViewController.venue.name);
```

and

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.tabBarController.venue.name);
```

But XCode gives the error

```
error: request for member 'venue' in something not a structure or union
```

I can access the venue property from within `MainViewController` just fine so have ruled out an error there. The iPhone simulator does see both `self.parentViewController` and `self.tabBarController` as an instance of `MainViewController`. The line...

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.tabBarController);
```

outputs...

```
2009-06-05 17:54:46.502 Venue[29729:20b] <MainViewController: 0x536600>
```

Since it's seen as a `MainViewController` instance, I doubt using casting would help. Is my only other option to initialize the `HomeViewController` with a copy of the venue or am I just doing something completely wrong with '`self.parentViewController.venue.name`'? Thanks, Rob

Comment: Have you set up venue and name as properties correctly? i.e. written KVC compliant accessors or used @property and @synthesize?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You're doing something completely wrong.  `parentViewController` is declared as a `UIViewController`.  `NSLog`ing it outputs its real type due to the wonders of polymorphism.

`UIViewController` doesn't have a `Venue` member.  Your `MainViewController` does.  Casting it is, in fact, the right answer.  Make sure to import `MainViewController.h` as well.

```
#import "MainViewController.h"
[...]
NSString *name = ((MainViewController *)self.parentViewController)).venue.name;
```

Also make sure, of course, that `venue` is declared as a `@property` of MainViewController, and `name` is a `@property` of `Venue`.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks. I had tried getting casting right earlier but messed my brackets allll up.

Comment: Great answer. I would suggest that the first sentence is unnecessary, though. It was a good question.

Comment: To be fair, his question was "Is my only other option to initialize the HomeViewController with a copy of the venue or am I just doing something completely wrong with 'self.parentViewController.venue.name'?"

Comment: Two years after the fact I'm here to tell @EdMarty that I saw the humor in his answer when he first wrote it. It's all good.

Comment: Yay! At least I don't look like a terrible person!

Comment: but as per the documentation of View Controllers, shouldn't the property parentViewController give a handle to the tab bar controller directly?

what is casting doing over here exactly? can u please explain @EdMarty ? i have a nav controllers that pushes (shows, ios 8) a VC that is a subclass of UIViewController. shouldnt parentViewController give me a handle to the Nav controller?

Comment: is it that the HomeViewController is a child to a UIController object which in turn is a child to a MainViewController?

your suggestion to the original post has worked in my case as well. but i wanna understand why it did

by the way, the 'presentingViewController' doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

```
int currentVCIndex = [self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self.navigationController.topViewController];

//previous view controller
AccountViewController *account = (AccountViewController *)[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:currentVCIndex - 1];

account.property = object;
[account doSmthng];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `NSLog()` statement is "seeing" it as a `MainViewController` because that's what the object actually is. The problem you're having though, is that the compiler doesn't actually realize this because the `parentViewController` property is declared as a plain old `UIViewController`. Even though you're actually returning a subclass of it, as far as the compiler knows you're trying to call that method on a `UIViewController`, and it's going to complain. Casting it to a `MainViewController` will solve the issue.