# Very basic objective-c question-how do I make different views share information?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, view

So, basically, I have four different views that are switched via a tab bar at the bottom of the screen. I have a view controller set up for each one, and they all work fine. The only problem is that I have no idea how to share information between the different views-for example, I have an IBAction on one that takes the output of a UISegmentedControl and stores the selection as an integer (1,2,3,4). The problem is, I don't know how to access that integer from the first view controller (the one that actually does stuff with that information). I'm sure this is a very basic problem but my google-fu doesn't seem to be working here. Thanks!

Comment: Nobody knows. It's too complicated and keeps changing all the time! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the MVC method, information should not be stored in the view controllers. You should have a separate object which stores the information, the view controllers load it, and the views display it. The easiest way to do this would be to store the information in your application's delegate. Then, whenever the view controller needs to find/change some information, it can use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]` to get the delegate, and load/change the information as needed. Load the information to update the display in viewDidLoad or viewWillDisplay:, and change it in action methods.

**Edit** Example:

DelegateClass.h

```
@interface DelegateClass : NSObject {
    //ivars
    float number1;
}
@property (assign) float number1;
...
@end
```

DelegateClass.m

```
#import "DelegateClass.h"
@implementation DelegateClass
@synthesize number1;
...
@end
```

MyViewController.m

```
#import "DelegateClass.h"
@implementation MyViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    DelegateClass *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    float number1 = delegate.number1;
    ...
}
- (IBAction)actionMethod:(id)sender {
    float number1 = sender.floatValue;//get new value
    ((DelegateClass*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).number1 = number1;
}
...
@end
```

Comment: okay, this has gotten me the farthest... again, I'm a real beginner at this, so how do I get a value from this? If I add a function to the app delegate, -(void)function1;, and then I do it elsewhere like [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] function1];, it compiles OK, but I get a warning, "'function1' not found in protocol", and I still don't know how to get or set a variable in the application delegate. Let's say I have a float called "number1", how can I do number1=1.0; or number2=number1; outside of the application delegate?

Comment: To get rid of your error, include the delegate's header file and cast the result of <code>delegate</code> to that class. I will add an example of getting/setting a property on the delegate.

Comment: OK, I'm getting further, but now I get the error "warning: type 'id <UIApplicationDelegate>' does not conform to the 'UITabBarControllerDelegate' protocol".

Comment: Try casting to id <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate>

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to do that. :\

Comment: Just put <code>(id <UIApplicationDelegate,UITabBarControllerDelegate>)</code> in front of the call which returns the object. Example: in my last update, I casted the return of the <code>delegate</code> method to a DelegateClass object.

Comment: Thank you so much! I now set values like 
"WaveGenAppDelegate *delegate =(id <UIApplicationDelegate,UITabBarControllerDelegate>)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
  delegate.number0=5.0;" 
and get values like 
WaveGenAppDelegate *delegate =(id <UIApplicationDelegate,UITabBarControllerDelegate>)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
testlabel1.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",delegate.number0];
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could have your views expose their variables to the `UITabBarController`. The `UITabBarController` can have methods that these views can call to see these variables.

Or, you could have your views directly set the values of variables in the `UITabBarController`. Not recommended (though a lot less typing :)

Just did a quick search on Google, btw, and came across this: [Accessing parent view controller (custom) properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956990/accessing-parent-view-controller-custom-properties). Looks like there's sample code to be had there. :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: OK, I feel really stupid asking this, but how do I access UITabBarController programmatically (there's only code for the app delegate as well as all of the views, but no code for the UITabBarController itself)? Do I just make a class for it and then, in interface builder, change the class from "UITabBarController" to my custom class? That's how I've been controlling these views.

Comment: Also, an equally stupid question, what do I call the instances of my views? All I do is write the code for them, but I never explicitly declare them/give them a name. Since that appears to happen automatically, I have no idea what to use when finding the value of a variable. I know it would look something like "newvalue=????.selectorValue", but I don't know what the ???? is, either when accessing values from the view or when the view is accessing variables from the UITabBarController.

Comment: I would suggest looking at the code by user387184 down below. He's using the app delegate to store globally accessible data. One drawback to that, though, is that the code isn't portable (I've gone down this path before).

Answer (score 0):

I use a general theme in all my apps where I have certain data that needs to be accessed practically in all main classes. I find it really easy to use and practically error free. (Thanks again to all the folks here in the forum for the super idea!)

I declare this variable in all the classes where I need it...

```
  @class WebiDataManager;

  @interface FirstViewController : UIViewController<MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate, SetupDelegate>  {
        WebiDataManager         *webiDataManager;
    ...
```

In this code I get it from the AppDelegate...

```
#import "WebiAppDelegate.h"

 - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        //  D_IN;
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];


        //get the dataManager global Object, so we always have a structured accesss to the data!
        WebiAppDelegate *mainDelegate = (WebiAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
        self.webiDataManager = mainDelegate.webiDataManager;
```

By the way, this also works great for coredata, since through this global variable I always have access to all the main coredata.

Hope I could explain it clearly enough...